# Unable to setup cloudera manager web on port 7180 - cluster installation

Tags: hadoop, installation, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am using ubuntu local machine with below hostname and trying to setup cloudera Hadoop Distribution CDH5.

```
chaithu@localhost:~$ hostname
localhost
chaithu@localhost:~$ hostname -f
localhost
chaithu@localhost:~$ ssh chaithu@localhost
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.8.0-36-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

449 packages can be updated.
232 updates are security updates.

Last login: Mon Dec 18 22:44:30 2017 from 127.0.0.1
```

Failed as Failed to detect root privileges with below error:

```
/tmp/scm_prepare_node.qkAAjdTz
using SSH_CLIENT to get the SCM hostname: 127.0.0.1 35708 22
opening logging file descriptor
Starting installation script...
Acquiring installation lock...
BEGIN flock 4
END (0)
Detecting root privileges...
effective UID is 1000
BEGIN which pbrun
END (1)
BEGIN sudo -S id
[sudo] password for chaithu:
END (1)
need root privileges but sudo requires password, exiting
closing logging file descriptor
```

Screen shot for where I am stuck with CDH installation.

[image]

Comment: What documentation did you follow to install things?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing sudo or passwordless sudo for the user which you are using for installation.

- Configure sudo for the user which is used for set up.
- Make sure passwordless sudo is configured for that user.

Comment: Hi Sachin, Thanks for you reply.  Yes I have included bleow lines in my /etc/sudoers file: chaithu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL and saved. even after that when I close the terminal and again tried command sudo cat /etc/sudoers is asking for password as shown below:                                                             chaithu@localhost:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
[sudo] password for chaithu:                                                                           could you pls help me on the same.